# Breakpoint Affecting ProcessCmdKey Processing of keyData

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard

Can anyone explain why the check for Alt+Left Arrow key is triggered on a Alt+Right Arrow key press within the ProcessCmdKey method? When I originally coded this method, everything worked. I am beginning to question all my key handlers, but wanted to know if there was a good explaination or if I am missing something. All other key combinations work as expected.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If (keyData And Keys.Alt) = Keys.Alt Then
        If (keyData And Keys.Left) = Keys.Left Then
            'when Alt+Right key is pressed
            '   this executes, except when a breakpoint is set anywhere within this method
            '   this still executes in released code
            Debug.WriteLine("WTF!")
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

The work around is to check for the key press as `If keyData = (Keys.Alt Or Keys.Left) Then`

[update]
Ah, I got it. Thank you Mitch. I did check for that, but missed it.

```
? convert.ToString(Keys.Left, 2)
"100101"
? convert.ToString(Keys.Right,2)
"100111"
```

Still would like to know why hitting the breakpoint changes behavior.

[update]
Thank you again Mitch. Since it wasn't reproducible for you, I suspect the solutions .suo file is corrupt. I deleted this file and now hitting the breakpoint has no affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Keys.Left  = 37 = 32 + 4     + 1
Keys.Right = 39 = 32 + 4 + 2 + 1
```

So bitwise, `Keys.Right` includes `Key.Left`. Therefore `And`ing with `Keys.Left` return `True` in either case.

Comment: I checked that. Why does it work properly when a breakpoint is set and execution stops?

Comment: Hmm, not reproducible on your computer, so it makes me wonder if the solutions .suo file is corrupt. I deleted .suo and now hitting the breakpoint has no affect.

Comment: @AMissico: that's interesting. I had no idea a problem with the .suo file could have such an effect...

Comment: Yes, interesting. It is something that just hit me to do because earlier I suggested to someone else to delete their .suo to fixed a different problem, and it worked. So I thought...breakpoints, weird behavior...delete .suo.